# Проблема получения данных с одного блока

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Есть у функция `ParseItem` для парсинга товара например: [Товар 1](https://prom.ua/p1180330579-kabel-multimedijnyj-minidisplay.html), [Товар 2](https://prom.ua/p1203034278-nabor-dlya-uhoda.html?).

Тут в качестве примера будет парситься **Товар 2**.

```cs
private async static Task ParseItem(string itemUrl)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C# App");
    HttpResponseMessage responce = await client.GetAsync(itemUrl);
    string source = default;
    if (responce != null && responce.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        source = await responce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    HtmlParser domParser = new HtmlParser();
    IHtmlDocument document = await domParser.ParseDocumentAsync(source);

    string name = document.QuerySelector("[data-qaid|=product_name]")?.InnerHtml;
    string price = document.QuerySelector("[data-qaid|=product_price]")?.Text();
    string code = document.QuerySelector("[data-qaid|=product-sku]")?.Text();
    string characteristics = document.QuerySelector("[data-qaid|=attributes]")?.Text();//Характеристики
    string company_name = document.QuerySelector("[data-qaid|=company_name]")?.InnerHtml;

    //Не могу получить данные переменные всегда будут == null
    string info_by_company = document.QuerySelector("[data-qaid|=info_by_company]")?.InnerHtml;
    var company_location = document.QuerySelector("[data-qaid|=company_location]");
    var phone = document.QuerySelector("[data-qaid|=phone]");
    var site = document.QuerySelector("[data-qaid|=site]");
    var schedule_block = document.QuerySelector("[data-qaid|=schedule_block]");
}

static async Task Main()
{

    await ParseItem("https://prom.ua/p1203034278-nabor-dlya-uhoda.html");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Проблема**: пытался каждый товар парсить, проблема всегда одна: не могу получить данные из блока (**рис.1**).

[image]

Comment: Вы так и не понимаете мой посыл. Ну не смотрите вы на UI, это не для вас. Вы, программист, работаете с кодом, ну так и работайте с ним! Вот скачайте HTML страничку программно и через поиск (ctrl+f) попробуйте найти имя продавца, вы найдете его в HTML блоках? Нет.. Вы его найдете в JSON, который находится в переменной `window.ApolloCacheState`.  Вот вам и [имена, фамилии, явки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH651.png) и [ценники с описанием и прочим](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKJ9v.png), берите да пользуйтесь...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ все понял ,но каким образом можно получить window.ApolloCacheState в с#?  Как понял выполнить с помощью anglesharp `window.ApolloCacheState` и получить результат,извините за вопрос я от веба очень далек.

Comment: Если вас есть пример буду очень блогадарен

Comment: Что вы используете чтобы так удобно смотреть значение тегов,как на картинке?

Comment: Не знаю, я всегда подобное вырезаю простым `Substring`, как с вашими новомодными библиотеками я без понятия. Вон набросал вам простейший [пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B3lJMd), но учтите, что там многое сделано "лишь бы работало" и вам стоит, например избавиться от `JObject` в пользу простой десериализации в класс, я лишь показал логику, по которой работает сайт, не более). JSON - да любой плагин для браузера, либо сайты на подобие `http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо вам,главное суть понял ваш пример поможет мне двигаться дальше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Json.Linq

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static class Ext
{
    public static string SubstringJson(this string value, string start, string end)
    {
        var startIndex = value.IndexOf(start) + start.Length;
        var endIndex = value.IndexOf(end) - startIndex;

        var result = value.Substring(startIndex, endIndex).Trim();
        return result.Remove(result.Length - 1);
    }

    public static int SubstringId(this string url)
    {
        var result = new Uri(url).AbsolutePath.Split('-').FirstOrDefault()?.Remove(0, 2);
        return int.Parse(result);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        var url = "https://prom.ua/p1180330579-kabel-multimedijnyj-minidisplay.html";
        var id = url.SubstringId();

        var json = await GetJsonAsync(url);
        var product = json[$"Product:{id}"];

        var name = product["name"];
        var price = product["price"];
        var priceLocalized = product["priceCurrencyLocalized"];
        var priceUSD = product["priceUSD"];

        var companyId = product["company"]["id"];
        var company = json[$"{companyId}"];
        var companyName = company["name"];
        var companyCity = company["city"];
        var companyPerson = company["contactPerson"];
        var companyPersonPhone = company["phone"];


        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendLine($"{name}");
        builder.AppendLine($"Цена {price} {priceLocalized} ({priceUSD} usd.) ");
        builder.AppendLine($"Компания: {companyName} (г.{companyCity})");
        builder.AppendLine($"Контакт: {companyPerson} ({companyPersonPhone})");
                
        Console.WriteLine(builder);
    }

    private static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(string url)
    {
        var html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        var jsonString = html.SubstringJson("window.ApolloCacheState =", "window.SPAConfig");
        return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
    }    
}
```

### Десериализовать  объект

**Product**

```
public class Product
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("price")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Price { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("priceUSD")]
        public string PriceUsd { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("priceCurrency")]
        public string PriceCurrency { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("priceCurrencyLocalized")]
        public string PriceCurrencyLocalized { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("discountedPrice")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long DiscountedPrice { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Есть скидка.
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("hasDiscount")]
        public bool hasDiscount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("priceOriginal")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long PriceOriginal { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sku")]
        public string Sku { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("images({\"height\":640,\"width\":640})")]
        public Images Images { get; set; }

        
        [JsonProperty("categoryId")]
        public long CategoryId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("urlForCanonical")]
        public Uri Catalog { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("keywords")]
        public string Keywords { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("urlForProductCatalog")]
        public Uri ProductCatalog { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("descriptionFull")]
        public string DescriptionFull { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("descriptionPlain")]
        public string DescriptionPlain { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("company_id")]
        public long CompanyId { get; set; }

        
        [JsonProperty("groupId")]
        public long GroupId { get; set; }
    }

   
    public  class Images
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("json")]
        public Uri[] Json { get; set; }
    }
```

**Converters**

```
public enum TypeEnum { Id };

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                TypeEnumConverter.Singleton,
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }

    internal class TypeEnumConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(TypeEnum) || t == typeof(TypeEnum?);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
            var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
            if (value == "id")
            {
                return TypeEnum.Id;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type TypeEnum");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (untypedValue == null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
                return;
            }
            var value = (TypeEnum)untypedValue;
            if (value == TypeEnum.Id)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, "id");
                return;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type TypeEnum");
        }

        public static readonly TypeEnumConverter Singleton = new TypeEnumConverter();
    }

    internal class ParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(long) || t == typeof(long?);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
            var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
            long l;
            if (Int64.TryParse(value, out l))
            {
                return l;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (untypedValue == null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
                return;
            }
            var value = (long)untypedValue;
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
            return;
        }

        public static readonly ParseStringConverter Singleton = new ParseStringConverter();
    }

    internal class JsonUnionConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(JsonUnion) || t == typeof(JsonUnion?);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.String:
                case JsonToken.Date:
                    var stringValue = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
                    return new JsonUnion { String = stringValue };
                case JsonToken.StartObject:
                    var objectValue = serializer.Deserialize<JsonJson>(reader);
                    return new JsonUnion { JsonJson = objectValue };
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type JsonUnion");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var value = (JsonUnion)untypedValue;
            if (value.String != null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value.String);
                return;
            }
            if (value.JsonJson != null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value.JsonJson);
                return;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type JsonUnion");
        }

        public static readonly JsonUnionConverter Singleton = new JsonUnionConverter();
    }
```

**Company**

```
    public  class Company
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("city")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ageYears")]
        public long AgeYears { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("opinionPositivePercent")]
        public long OpinionPositivePercent { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("opinionTotal")]
        public long OpinionTotal { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("opinionTotalInRating")]
        public long OpinionTotalInRating { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Все товары продавца.
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("urlForCompanyProducts")]
        public Uri CompanyProducts { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// ?
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("portalPageURL")]
        public Uri PortalPage{ get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Представитель компании.
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("contactPerson")]
        public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
       
        [JsonProperty("contactEmail")]
        public object ContactEmail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("mainLogoUrl({\"height\":50,\"width\":100})")]
        public Uri Logo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("webSiteUrl")]
        public Uri WebSite { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Отзывы
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("companyOpinionsUrl")]
        public Uri CompanyOpinions { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Варианты доставки
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("deliveryOptions({\"itemsPrices\":[],\"productIds\":[]})")]
        public DeliveryOptions DeliveryOptions { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("phones")]
        public Phones Phones { get; set; }

  
        [JsonProperty("regionName")]
        public string RegionName { get; set; }

      
        [JsonProperty("phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }

    public  class DeliveryOptions
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("json")]
        public DeliveryOptionsItemsPricesProductIdsJson[] Json { get; set; }
    }

    public  class DeliveryOptionsItemsPricesProductIdsJson
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("comment")]
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name_without_price")]
        public string NameWithoutPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("self_delivery_in_name")]
        public bool SelfDeliveryInName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("min_price")]
        public object MinPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("delivery_price")]
        public object DeliveryPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("free_delivery_price")]
        public long? FreeDeliveryPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("free_delivery")]
        public bool FreeDelivery { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("apply_to_total")]
        public bool ApplyToTotal { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("position")]
        public long? Position { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hidden")]
        public bool Hidden { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("from_last_name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public bool? FromLastName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("address_street", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public bool? AddressStreet { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("prices")]
        public Prices Prices { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }
    }

    public  class Prices
    {
        [JsonProperty("priceTotals")]
        public object[] PriceTotals { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("rawTotalPriceInDefaultCurrency")]
        public long RawTotalPriceInDefaultCurrency { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("priceTotalsDefaultCurrency")]
        public long PriceTotalsDefaultCurrency { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("priceTotalsInUSD")]
        public long PriceTotalsInUsd { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("priceTotalsHtml")]
        public long PriceTotalsHtml { get; set; }
    }

    public  class Phones
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("json")]
        public JsonUnion[] Json { get; set; }
    }

    public  class JsonJson
    {
        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    public  struct JsonUnion
    {
        public JsonJson JsonJson;
        public string String;

        public static implicit operator JsonUnion(JsonJson JsonJson) => new JsonUnion { JsonJson = JsonJson };
        public static implicit operator JsonUnion(string String) => new JsonUnion { String = String };
    }
```

**Extension**

```
static class Ext
    {
        public static string SubstringJson(this string value, string start, string end)
        {
            var startIndex = value.IndexOf(start) + start.Length;
            var endIndex = value.IndexOf(end) - startIndex;

            var result = value.Substring(startIndex, endIndex).Trim();
            return result.Remove(result.Length - 1);
        }

        public static int SubstringId(this string url)
        {
            var result = new Uri(url).AbsolutePath.Split('-').FirstOrDefault()?.Remove(0, 2);
            return int.Parse(result);
        }
    }
```

**Method GetJsonAsync**

```
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        private static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(string url)
        {
            var html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            var jsonString = html.SubstringJson("window.ApolloCacheState =", "window.SPAConfig");
            return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        }
```

**Method ParseItem**

```
        private async static Task ParseItem(string itemUrl)
        {
           
            var id = itemUrl.SubstringId();

            var json = await GetJsonAsync(itemUrl);
            var product = json[$"Product:{id}"];
            var Product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(product.ToString());
            
            var companyId = product["company"]["id"];
            var company = json[$"{companyId}"];
            var Company = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Company>(company.ToString());
            
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.AppendLine($"{Product.Name}");

            builder.AppendLine($"Картинки");
            foreach(var image in Product.Images.Json)
            {
                builder.AppendLine($"{image}");
            }
            builder.AppendLine($"Цена {Product.Price} {Product.PriceCurrencyLocalized} ({Product.PriceUsd} usd.) ");
            builder.AppendLine($"Компания:{Company.Name} г.{Company.City}");
            builder.AppendLine($"Контакт: {Company.ContactPerson} {Company.Phone} {Company.WebSite}");
            

            Console.WriteLine(builder);
        }
```

**Main**

```
        static async Task Main()
        {

            await ParseItem("https://prom.ua/p1097470680-halat-zhenskij-dlinnyj.html");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

[Код реализации](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qcQFM0)

Comment: Боже, как тяжело понять код, состоящий только из сплошных `var`. Это реально кому-то нравится? Жесть же.

Comment: @aepot Боже, вы опять за свое, ну говорили ведь на эту тему, не нравиться, пройдите мимо. Ей богу, все время навязываете свое мировоззрение, зачем? Вот я как автор кода выше отвечу на ваш вопрос: да, нравиться, многим людям, которые знают, что вернет метод и не хотят тратить время на постоянное написание типа. Это удобно, быстро, легко.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ [о чем вы вообще?](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions#implicitly-typed-local-variables)

Comment: @aepot Самая первая строка `В случаях, когда тип переменной понятен из правой части назначения или когда точный тип не важен, рекомендуется использовать неявное типизирование для локальных переменных.`.  Сама Microsoft рекомендует использовать `var`, когда тип не важен или когда он и так известен. Где в коде выше хоть одно место, где нужно строго знать тип? Где что либо, где тип непонятен? Вот просто придирка в пустоту, серьезно, дайте мне хоть один довод, чтоб код выше был переписан с указанием явного типа, кроме ваших "хотелок".

Comment: @ EvgeniyZ мне тоже все понятно,когда вы навели на переменную тип данных показывает.

Comment: Навожу мышь на ваш код - ничего не показывает. Но вам виднее, конечно. Я просто сказал, что мне сложно читать выше показанный код. Пришел опять @EvgeniyZ и наворчал на меня, но вот если бы от этого код стал читабельнее - был бы в этом смысл. Этот ответ бесполезен для других посетителей, так как его очень сложно прочитать.

Comment: @aepot Я на вас не наворчал, я попытался от вас услышать внятное объяснение вашей претензии и обосновать снятие репутации с человека (минус на ответ), вы это до сих пор не сделали, обосновав это тем, что вам трудно читать. Трудно - читайте значит книжки, понимайте как в C# устроено все, а других пожалуйста, не судите по себе! Я еще раз повторю, мне этот код будет всегда понятен и я всегда предпочту такой вариант, почему? Да потому что тут без разницы какой тип.

Comment: @aepot К примеру `var companyName = company["name"];` - нам важно знать тип этой строки, если мы все равно переведем ее в `string`? Нет, именования достаточно для понимания того, что она содержит в себе. Или `var url = "https://...";`, ну что, нам тут не ясно, что это строка?

Comment: @aepot Единственное, к чему бы я принял претензию, так это к `var id = url.SubstringId();` и то тут проблема в именовании, ибо `Substring` - это строковая операция, но `var` я бы не убрал, почему? Да все по тем же причинам, без разницы что за `id`, ибо он нужен лишь для преобразования в `string` и, по сути, то, что я методом возвращаю `int` можно тоже убрать и возвращать строку, ибо тип не важен. Так что повторюсь, не судите по себе, учитесь значит понимать код и не критикуйте без повода, ибо сколько людей, столько и мнений и вы сами показали, что Microsoft рекомендует использовать `var`.

Comment: @ EvgeniyZ Вопрос еще как можно сайта вытянуть JSON? Спарсить его? Чтобы посмотреть какие данные в него есть. Как у вас на картинке.

Comment: Поглядел на код. Дискомфорта не испытал. Что я делаю не так? :) @aepot

Comment: @Vladimir `Ctrl+C` -> `Ctrl+V`)  Вам ведь сайт не дают ссылку или что либо еще, а дает сразу готовую JSON строку, копируйте ее из html исходников и вставляйте в нужный редактор, либо вон код выше, строка `var jsonString = html.SubstringJson(...);` содержит в себе то, что отдает вам сайт.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ еще вам огромное спасибо

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Добавил десериализации в класс  [Код](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qcQFM0) ,но проблема в том не знаю как правильно пометить класс атрибутом чтобы `[JsonProperty("Product:id")]`-айди товара подставлялся нужный для продукта и компанией тоже самое. У меня  потому не удалось избавиться от `JObject`.

Comment: Кхм... Всем: в старые добрые времена была такая технология: COM. Если бы хипстеры её осилили, то подсветка кода в браузерах (и вообще где угодно) осуществлялась бы _компилиторами_ языков программирования, а не регексами, как сейчас. Тогда бы интеллисенс работал в браузере так же, как в IDE. PS: вы ворчите, а мне нельзя, что ли?

Comment: @Vladimir Это уже совсем другой вопрос, на который я так с ходу вряд ли смогу вам помочь. Там скорей всего надо сделать конвертор, который сопоставит все эти данные в классы, а в них я не силен)  Я кстати понаблюдал за запросами, что отправляет сервер, оказывается там используется GraphQL, все запросы посылаются на `POST: https://prom.ua/graphql`, тело содержит JSON, где указывается что именно [нужно запросить](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ihMw.png). Так что можете попробовать через него общаться с сервером, запрашивать только ту инфу, что вам нужна.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Если там есть нужные данные(GraphQL) можно взять от туда,код который  написал он работает  только осталось понять как его оптимизировать(если товаром будет 5 тысяч какая будет скорость получения данных) и подумать как  улучшить код.

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov если вы знайте как реализовать COM(для моей задачи), дайте пример как работать с данной технологией(ни разу,не работал данной технологией) в с#.